# Pandasql: sqldf executing error

Tags: python, pandas, sqldf, pandasql

I want to execute sql-query "SELECT 1" using pandasql. But there is an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\AdminVAIO\Documents\Visual Studio
 2013\Projects\crm\crm\crm.py", line 47, in <module>

     print(ps.sqldf(s, locals()))

   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 155, in
 sqldf

     return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)

   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 61, in
 __call__

     result = read_sql(query, conn)    

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 421, in read_sql

     coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates)    
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1046, in read_sql

      cursor = self.execute(*args)    
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1025, in execute

     cur = self.con.cursor()

 AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'

 Press any key to continue . . .
```

here is the code (Python 3.4, pandasql 0.7.1, pandas 0.14.1):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

s = """
SELECT 1
"""
print(ps.sqldf(s, locals()))
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
pip install -U pandasql
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, it works!

I've just installed pandas 0.17.0 instead of 0.14.1